# remove entries from DOI queue

Tags: dspace

Dspace queues all new items to be submitted to DataCite for DOIs.  I'd like to remove some items from that queue.  Is there a command line option with the doi-organiser that can do that, or will I need to edit the database?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the "doi-organiser" command, for example:

```
./dspace doi-organiser --delete-doi {DOI}
```

replace {DOI} with the DOI you would like to remove from the queue.

Comment: This deletes a registered or reserved item in the table, but not one that hasn't yet been submitted to DataCite.

   ` -bash-4.1$ /ir/dspace/bin/dspace doi-organiser -l  `

   ` There are no DOIs queued for reservation. ` 

   ` DOIs queued for registration:   `
        doi:10.5072/ucrrtest-22 (belongs to item with handle 123456789/11368)`  

   ` There are no DOIs queued for update. ` 

    `There are no DOIs queued for deletion.  `
    `-bash-4.1$ /ir/dspace/bin/dspace doi-organiser -d 10.5072/ucrrtest-22` 

   ` There are no objects in the database that could be deleted.`